# Make quickfix buffer modifiable

Tags: vim

Currently, I'm trying to clean the quickfix window while using cscope and to do that I'm using these commands:

```
augroup quickfix
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufRead qf set modifiable
    autocmd FileType qf
                \   set modifiable        |
                \   set hidden            |
                \   execute ":%s/<<.*>>//g"
augroup END
```

This way whenever a file is opened the `<<>>` tags are removed. However,  since by default the quickfix window is `nomodifiable` I'm having to force it.

During testing I found that the replacement is executed but the quickfix window is still `nomodifiable` afterward; therefore I cannot edit its content or use it as notes. Modifiable can be set by hand once the window is opened, but this is not convenient. Maybe I`m missing something or using the wrong event. Can someone explain what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's not urgent to deal with `autogroup` before you are familiar to them enough.

Just try or do it in your .vimrc with a line like below:

`au BufRead errors.err set ma hidden | execute ":%s/<<.*>>//g"`

then the quickfix file (usually named as 'errors.err') should be modifiable.

(If you use a different name, substitute it for the 'errors.err', or use a pattern like '*.err'.)

See `:h au` for further info.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is something inherently inefficient about your process of using the quickfix list, but if you wanted to abuse it this way and make it modifiable the following works for me:

```
au! FileType qf set ma hidden | execute ":%s/<<.*>>//g"
au! BufReadPost quickfix set ma
```

See `:h CTRL-W-<Enter>` for some further information.